# WebsitePanel 2 totally NOT working on Windows Server 2012 on Azure

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I’m having many troubles installing WebSitePanel on an Azure Virtual Machine, with Windows Server 2012.
 I followed the steps in http://www.websitepanel.net/documentation/deployment-guide/server-configuration/preparing-windows-server-2008-r2-for-websitepanel-installation/ and installed everything I needed.

Then, I installed the WebSitePanel Standalone Server package with the installer.
 I opened the endpoint for the port 9002 on Windows Azure; so I pointed my browser to myhostname.cloudapp.net (note: in Azure you don’t have a static IP address, instead you have an hostname like [hostname].cloudapp.net).
 So, loading myhostname.cloudapp.net:9002 fails, and any browser shows something like “Unable to load page”. I think it’s a 400 or a 500 server error.

How come?
IIS works perfectly on the server, in fact the default website runs without problems on port 80.

Comment: This should be posted on SuperUser or ServerFault since it's not a programming question. That said: Did you confirm WebsitePanel installed correctly, by RDP'ing into your VM and trying to visit localhost:9002?

Comment: Thanks for advice, I've posted it on ServerFault.
However, nope. WebsitePanel doesn't work even in localhost: I get an HTTP 400 Bad request when I try to reach localhost:9002.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you change the binding to another IP address.

Usually I fix this situation by going to the IIS control panel where I change binding back to 127.0.0.1:9002

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found the correct solution yet :

edit your hosts file under `system32/drivers/etc` and put the url you have set up during the installation there with your local ip

You should be able to access websitepanel portal with the url